fallaną from (s)gʷʰh₂el instead of h₂epo + h₃elh₁ ? (PIE -> germanic)
My native language is Dutch and I always assumed that the Latin "fallere" and "vallen" would have the same root in PIE. To my surprise, everywhere online I find that this is not the case and that the former comes from Greek σφάλλω and in turn from PIE (s)gʷʰh₂el- (to stumble), while the latter comes from Germanic fallaną and in turn from PIE h₂epo (off, away) + h₃elh₁- (to fall). I find good evidence online for the existence of the latter in PIE, like the Greek ἀπόλλῡμι (to destroy, kill), and in Old Prussian aupallai (to find) (https://www.etymonline.com/word/fall).
However, I still feel like fallaną should be closer to gʷʰh₂el- than to the other. I am not an expert in etymology so my question is: Is this possible or is it too strange?

It seems extremely unlikely at first glance. By Grimm’s Law, PIE *gʷʰ becomes (Pre-)Proto-Germanic *gʷ – which, in turn, becomes PG *b in initial position pretty much everywhere. If PIE *gʷʰh₂el- were Germanicised, we’d expect it to yield **bal- (cf. PIE *gʷʰen- ‘kill’ > En. bane; PIE *gʷʰedʰ-i̯e/o- ‘asks’ > En. bid), which is not found anywhere in Germanic. // Side note: Lat. fallere is not from Greek σφάλλω, but cognate with it.

**bal? Surely you must you mean ball, bale, bulla? (φαλλός)

Latin fallō is not from σφάλλω, it's cognate with it. Both are from *(s)gʷʰh₂el- but different formations. The Latin is from *(s)gʷʰh₂él-s-eti (an s-present), whilst the Greek is from *(s)gʷʰh₂él-y-eti (a ye-present).
The Germanic reflex of PIE *gʷʰ is actually somewhat unclear. Word-internally, the outcome seems to be *w intervocalically, and *gw otherwise. Word-initially it's less clear, with one camp arguing for *b on the basis of apparent examples like English bid from PIE *gʷʰédʰ-y-eti "to be asking", and another arguing for *w on the basis of apparent examples like English warm from PIE *gʷʰór-m-os "warm". As far as I know, Proto-Germanic *warmaz is the only reasonably likely example of the latter reflex though, whilst the *b reflex has several other good examples, so it seems most likely that *b is the genuine word-initial reflex and *warmaz is a result of some unclear conditioning or dialect mixing, or more likely, has some other etymology (e.g. from *wer- "to burn").
Regardless, a Germanic reflex of *gʷʰ is certainly not *f (the source of Dutch initial v) in any position. Proto-Germanic *f has just one PIE origin: *p.
As such, the Germanic cognate of Latin fallō would be *balsaną (giving Dutch *balsen) or perhaps *walsaną (giving Dutch *walsen); and the Germanic cognate of Greek σφάλλω would be *spaljaną (giving Dutch *spellen) or perhaps *swaljaną (giving Dutch *zwellen).
The etymology of Dutch vallen (Proto-Germanic *fallaną, English fall) is less clear, as the sort of fossilised preverb proposed to explain it (i.e. *h₂p-h₃elh₁-n-éti "to be falling off" or *h₂p-h₃olh₁-n-éti from *h₂epo "away" & *h₃elh₁- "to fall") is not especially common, but certainly seems plausible, and the Greek cognate is (potentially) exact (although it could also be formed with the preverb *h₂epo intact).

A connection between vallen and σφαλλω has long been suggested and dismissed, like many other equations. The question presents itself:

Is this possible or is it too strange?

It's possible that vallen is from *(s)gʷʰh₂el- by syllogism if vallen is from **h₂p-h₃elh₁- and this in turn from: *gʷʰh₂el-, *sbHel, **(s)pHel-.
The last step is pretty much guaranteed because there is no evidence of Germanic sb, and there is the rare notion of *p despite of Grimm's law, potentially from *(s)p. Greek on the other hand has σφ despite of Siebs' law.
Andrew Byrd discusses σφαλλω briefly, arguing that *P + *H is difficult to reconstruct and that "Perhaps, however, this root’s reconstructable voiceless aspirate may be attributed to Siebs’ Law (*s + Dh → *sTh) and not to the cluster *PH." (Byrd 2015:101-102)
This requires reconstructing the vowel *a post-PIE instead of the laryngeal formalism *h₂e. This reduces the difference to *h₃e because Germanic *a < *o < *e is possible in the full grade of the root or zero grade of the prefix *h₂epo ~ *Hpo if that's what it is. Yet PIE *a is not generally accepted.
However, the same is true to a lesser extent of the Germanic outcome of *gʷʰ (thus Seebold, if I remember correctly). Perhaps I just haven't taken the time to convince myself of the communis opinio. Cf. Lloyd et al., "gerade die oberflächliche Zusammenstellung von gr. φον- und germ. *ban- hat die Forschung immer wieder irregeführt, s. etwa Lexer, Schade, Dt. Wb., OED u. a., dagegen Persson, Stud. z. Wurzelerw. 73." (EWAhd 1989: bano). And against this the Wintionary, bane of my existence < *gʷʰen-.
Two remaining problems seem to be i. the laryngeal coda of *peh3lH- ‘vallen’ (LIV, apud EWNl; see a similar problem with wool) and ii.a) that there is no good reason to equate *(s)gʷʰ- with *Hp(o)-, *h₂epo, ii.b) that s-mobile is unexplained.
So it might just be the other way around, since the typologically common development seems to be /p/ > /f x/ > /h/.

To address some concerned comments:
The point of my take on Siebs' law is that there is no aspirated voiceless *pʰ in the consonant system of PIE. Byrd 2015 does not acknowledge Siebs' in the list of phonological "conspiracies" as he so aptly put it. Plain *p is expected at least from the Germanic point of view, notwithstanding Greek. There is scarcely any evidence to the opposite:

σφαραγέομαι "to crackle, sizzle" (Beekes 2010) – strikes me as imitative – comparison to Old English sprecan "speak" (o.c.) is usually considered uncertain, maybe unrelated (Kroonen 2013).
Note that this is the only example out of 34 under σφ in Beekes' Etymological Dictionary of Greek:
Three lemmas point to σπ. One lemma, i.e. σφάλλω reconstructs *(s)gʷʰ, remainig lemmas are uncertain.

σφήξ "wasp" (Kölligan 2020, in: Indogermanische Forschungen) – suspect of being imitative (cf. Bjørn 2023:28, in: Historische Sprachforschung) – Beekes w.f.r. considers pre-Greek with ψήν, thus already Frisk–Johnson.
I told him he his wrong about PIE *(s)bʰ, he recommended with a hint of irony that I publish my findings. At last but not least I can say I have finally understood that Siebs' law as elaborated by @Tristan and @Cairnavon does not prohibit σφ, since I havent read Siebs (cf. Byrd loc. cit.) and blindly followed Wikipedia:

"According to this law, if an s-mobile is added to a root that starts with a voiced or aspirated stop, that stop is allophonically devoiced.


Compare:



PIE *bʰr̥Hg- > Latin fragor, but *s-bʰr̥Hg- > PIE *spʰr̥Hg- > Sanskrit sphūrjati.
(https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Siebs's_law)


According to the letter of the law I might consider /*pʰ/ allophone to /*p/, notably if /*b/ allophone to /*bʰ pʰ/, status of *b debatable for "Proto-Indo-Celtic" (Olander 2022). A system without *b but *bʰ is typologically deviant (Ivanov and Gamkrelidze, passim; most recently Kortlandt 2022, in: Journal of Indo-European studies).

Vedic sphuráti "jerk, kick" vs. bhuráti "jerk, quiver, move rapidly" (Southern per Byrd 2015: 102 fn 62) – no comparison in Greek.


All in all this is the million dollar question on a shoe string budget.
Note that these could easily be related to σφαλλω, especially sphuráti if the vowel assimilated to labial (cf. Mayrhofer, Indogermanische Grammatik. 1, Lindner (ed.), 2012, s.v. "puri"), r ~ l allophone in Indo-Iranian, also pre-Greek. Note in particular asparagus, ἀσφάρᾰγος, formerly PIE **(s)pregʰ-* "to jerk, to scatter", cp. σφαραγέομαι "to burst with a noise, teem" (IEW), "... Beekes rejects this, citing a Pre-Greek origin due to the presence of the variation "π/φ"." (apud Wiktionary). See likewise German springen "to spring, jump; crack", sprengen "to burst, explode; spray" (cf. σπέρχομαι, *sperģʰ- vs. springan, *sprengʰ-, following LIV²) – Note homophone ἀσφάρᾰγος "throat, gullet".
On one of the three remaing suspects in EDG:

σφόγγοσ, σπόγγοσ "sponge" – together with Armenian sownkn usually analyzed as substrate word as most recently discussed by Thorsø 2023: "After all, however, it is more likely that the Kartvelian and Armenian forms are both independent borrowings from Nakh-Daghestanian languages, [...]" (R. T. Nielsen [Thorsø], "Prehistoric Loanwords in Armenian", dissertation, Leiden, 2023:83), here also fungus etc. (Thorsø 2023:205-207 w.f.r.).


Apart from anything else, *gʷʰ > φ before back vowels is the regular development in Greek, and Siebs's law doesn't affect it one bit. The difficulty in reconstructing a PIE preform for σφάλλω lies purely in squaring it with a supposed cognate in Sanskrit skhalati, not anything Greek-internal.

Byrd's formulation of Sieb's is clear, aspirated stops become devoiced. Don't take it out on me. The backvowel would be effective after loss of laryngeals and thus after operation of Siebs. Since there is no voiceless aspirated velar or labial, loss of aspiration is only logical, phonology 101: spit [p] vs. pit [pʰ].

@vectory a devoiced voiced aspirate is a voiceless aspirate, not a plain voiceless stop. Afaict, it's unclear the extent to which Greek inherits such post-Siebs'-Law voiceless aspirates as plain voiceless stops (deaspirating them), or leaving them as is (merging them back into the voiced aspirates), so σφ- < *s-gʷʰ- is entirely plausible (before back vowels at least). And sure, English deaspirates after s-, but this isn't a phonetic universal, plenty of languages do allow aspirates after s (including elsewhere in Greek, which has plenty of -σθ- clusters in the passive)

Yeah, Siebs's law does say voiced aspirates allophonically devoice, but they specifically don't deaspirate as well—much of the point of Siebs's law is to serve as an explanation for some of the voiceless aspirates in Indo-Iranian.

Isn't the whole point of Siebs's Law is that it creates voiceless aspirated stops, not voiceless unaspirated ones? Presumably during the period in which the Law operated these were allophones of the voiced aspirated stops, but later they split entirely (at least in Indo-Iranian which is why Siebs's Law exists). Also, yes, lacking /b/ is typologically unusual, which is why many linguists argue that *b wasn't actually /b/, but that has nothing to do with Siebs's Law.

how would Siebs' law justify [*pʰ] as an allophone of /*p/? It'd clearly be an allophone of /*bʰ/ which occurs following an s-mobile (but not following other s, something somewhat troubling for the status of Siebs' law). The potential argument for [*pʰ] as an allophone of /*p/ would apply only in pre-laryngeal position. The fact that two separate phonemes can share an allophone is not at all unusual ofc. English has [b̥] as an allophone of /p/ after word-initial s, and as an allophone of /b/ word-initially (and in several other environments) for instance

@Tristan, I'd rather say that's troubling for the status of s-mobile.

@Tristan, Your post is conversational, by the way, since I already addressed the relevant evidence. More evidence is always welcome, but yours is simply an opinion (even if a common one, you know the saying, and I say this after exceeding the comment length twice trying to respond).
